# Dynamically create variable with sass in list

Tags: sass

Basically, I'm trying to generate a lot of styles, each containing an image and a color. Colors are listed and variables are named the same way. The problem is I can't have Sass to use the dynamically generated name (near a{color }. But is it possible to use it this way ? Thanks !

```
$color-style-winter: #11111;
$color-style-christmas: #22222;

$styles: 'winter' 'hills',
  'christmas' 'xmas';

@each $name, $image in $styles {
    .style-#{$name} {
        background: url('../../images/styles/#{$image}.jpg');
    }

    a {
        color: $color-style- + $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question fully but have a look on SASS interpolation Docs and the article provided. Use placeholder.

The code could look like:

```
%my-style-test1 {color: red;}
%my-style-test2 {color: blue;}

$style: 'test1' 'test2';

@each $name in $style {

  a {

    @extend %my-style-#{$name};

  }

}
```

CSS:

```
a {
        color: red;
    }

a {
        color: blue;
    }
```

the example is a bit useless but shows how to use % placholder and interpolation

[SASS Docs interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)
[SASS Articel Interpolation](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Two-handy-and-advanced-SASS-features-and-their-limitations)

Comment: This is what I did a first, but the compiler is not OK with it : 'Undefined variable: "$color-style-".'
I also tried to concatenate but this is not using the variable value, only writing the variable name in the generated css :
    color: unquote('$color-style-' + $name);
generates: 
    color: $color-style-christmas;

Comment: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/SASS-interpolation-in-a-name-of-variable-nest-variables-within-variables

Comment: Thanks again, but this is not working as I expect. I'll keep using a 3-entries list, which is the simplest solution at the moment !