# Get sass variable-value instead of variable-name

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have multiple color variables which have a darker contrast color which are outside any sass map.
For example:

```
$wp-colors: (
    $primary: #04285b;
    $secondary: #f6bb20;
}
$primary-d: #032048; // contrast color
$secondary-d: #99f700; // contrast color
```

For simplicity, I want to make a loop to use the contrast color when hovering a `.btn`.

In my project, I created the following loop:

```
@each $color, $value in $wp-colors {
    .btn-#{$color}:hover {
        background-color: #{$value}#{-d};
    }
}
```

But this outputs in:

```
.btn-secondary:hover{background-color:secondary-d}
```

While I want the value of `$secondary-d`, like so:

```
.btn-secondary:hover{background-color:#99f700}
```

How do I get the color value of the variable with the appended letter?

Comment: why not just create a `$wp-colours-dark`, then you can use `map-get` in your loop: https://jsfiddle.net/9q6rwhnb/

Comment: You may change two-dimensional map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535744/dynamically-create-variable-with-sass-in-list

Comment: @Pete, this must be the best solution I think indeed. Thanks for the clarification!